# How to inject Models, Services in all Controllers by default while creating a node js app with express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sails.js

I have a little experience with Sails and I really like the way it automatically injects all the models and services inside controllers so we save ourself from requiring all those at the beginning of the script, but the framework is very bulky.

So, I am making a project using express framework and want to implement this feature where I do not need to require Services and Models in each and every Controller script.

Thanks.

Comment: No, it won't happen by default. You would have to require modules manually.

Comment: I know it wont happen by default. I just wanted to now if there is any way to do that. It becomes cumbersome to include a lot of modules. There can be a way where we can store all the references in env and then access all those references from it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can create a index file for exporting all services and models. Then just include it into your controllers

in service.js

```
exports = {
    auth    : require('./auth'),
    user    : require('./user'),
    and many more
}
```

in controller

```
var service = require('service')
```

use services as service.auth, service.user

Thanks

Comment: this is clever. Thanks :)